# Postgis Query Construction - postgresql

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap

I'm a newbie and I need a little bit help with postgis query construction. My situation looks like this.
I have a table in postgresql with ways converted from bicycle routes (take from Open Street Map).
If there are 2 or more routes on the same way, the lines are overlapping on each other and have exactly the same geometry but have different tags (name, ref etc)
I would like to add another column with a counter for these duplicated lines. Let's say that I have 3 bicycle routes on the same way, this equals to 3 lines overlapping each other. These should get an extra tag with a number 1, 2 and 3. This should happend only if there are more than 2 overlapping lines. If there is only one, no number should be added.

I tried ST_Equals but can't get it to work....

Here's my code which is not exactly for this purpose but for merging lines with the same attributes. I would like to add the counters into it.

```
DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS  public.bicycle_merge;
CREATE TABLE public.bicycle_merge AS
SELECT ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(way)) AS way,reversed,route, osmc_color,name, network, state, "instance:cycle", "relation:id", ref, description, distance
  FROM planet_osm_line
  WHERE route IN ('bicycle')
  GROUP BY   reversed, route, osmc_color,name, network, state, "instance:cycle", "relation:id", ref, description, distance
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. It is policy here that coding questions must provide code. Please **edit** the question to contain descriptions of the tables and the SQL you had tried.

Answer (score 3):

Without having actual data, I'd guess you could use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/tutorial-window.html) ([+ interesting blog post on the topic](http://tapoueh.org/blog/2013/08/20-Window-Functions)). Something like `select row_number() over (partition by ST_LineMerge(ST_Collect(way))) as overlap_count` could work.

Comment: Hi Tkan. I have to change my strategy. Your solution actually worked but I need something slightly different. How can I find unique geometries in my table and add a column which will contain for example letter "U"? All overlaping geometries should be blank in this column.

Comment: Geometries can be grouped like any other column. You'd find them by using `group by geometry` and `having count(*) = 1`. This would display all geometries which are unique in the table. And those overlapping ones can be added by using `UNION ALL` and `having count(*) > 1`.